# Why does my BULK INSERT code skip (ignore) the 1st row?

Tags: sql

```
BULK INSERT CDR FROM 'C:\sqldata\myDatafile.txt' 
WITH (FORMATFILE='C:\sqldata\CDRimport.fmt', FIRSTROW=3)
```

I have a problem which cause a headache for me and appreciate your help. My problem is that I'm pulling data from flat files to SQL Server 2008 using `BULK INSERT` with `FORMATFILE`.

Everything is working fine and the data is being loaded successfully. However I noticed that the 1st row is always been skipped (ignored). I'm setting `FIRSTROW=3` to start from the 3rd row because the 1st contains headers and the 2nd contains datatype and I don't want them to be imported.

To test my case you need the following:

First: create this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CDR](
[cdrRecordType] [varchar](50) NULL,
[globalCallID_callManagerId] [varchar](50) NULL,
[globalCallID_callId] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origLegCallIdentifier] [varchar](50) NULL,
[dateTimeOrigination] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origNodeId] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origSpan] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origIpAddr] [varchar](50) NULL,
[callingPartyNumber] [varchar](50) NULL,
[callingPartyUnicodeLoginUserID] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origCause_location] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origCause_value] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origPrecedenceLevel] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origMediaTransportAddress_IP] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origMediaTransportAddress_Port] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origMediaCap_payloadCapability] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origMediaCap_maxFramesPerPacket] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origMediaCap_g723BitRate] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origVideoCap_Codec] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origVideoCap_Bandwidth] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origVideoCap_Resolution] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origVideoTransportAddress_IP] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origVideoTransportAddress_Port] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origRSVPAudioStat] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origRSVPVideoStat] [varchar](50) NULL,
[destLegIdentifier] [varchar](50) NULL,
[destNodeId] [varchar](50) NULL,
[destSpan] [varchar](50) NULL,
[destIpAddr] [varchar](50) NULL,
[originalCalledPartyNumber] [varchar](50) NULL,
[finalCalledPartyNumber] [varchar](50) NULL,
[finalCalledPartyUnicodeLoginUserID] [varchar](50) NULL,
[destCause_location] [varchar](50) NULL,
[destCause_value] [varchar](50) NULL,
[destPrecedenceLevel] [varchar](50) NULL,
[destMediaTransportAddress_IP] [varchar](50) NULL,
[destMediaTransportAddress_Port] [varchar](50) NULL,
[destMediaCap_payloadCapability] [varchar](50) NULL,
[destMediaCap_maxFramesPerPacket] [varchar](50) NULL,
[destMediaCap_g723BitRate] [varchar](50) NULL,
[destVideoCap_Codec] [varchar](50) NULL,
[destVideoCap_Bandwidth] [varchar](50) NULL,
[destVideoCap_Resolution] [varchar](50) NULL,
[destVideoTransportAddress_IP] [varchar](50) NULL,
[destVideoTransportAddress_Port] [varchar](50) NULL,
[destRSVPAudioStat] [varchar](50) NULL,
[destRSVPVideoStat] [varchar](50) NULL,
[dateTimeConnect] [varchar](50) NULL,
[dateTimeDisconnect] [varchar](50) NULL,
[lastRedirectDn] [varchar](50) NULL,
[pkid] [varchar](50) NULL,
[originalCalledPartyNumberPartition] [varchar](50) NULL,
[callingPartyNumberPartition] [varchar](50) NULL,
[finalCalledPartyNumberPartition] [varchar](50) NULL,
[lastRedirectDnPartition] [varchar](50) NULL,
[duration] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origDeviceName] [varchar](50) NULL,
[destDeviceName] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origCallTerminationOnBehalfOf] [varchar](50) NULL,
[destCallTerminationOnBehalfOf] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origCalledPartyRedirectOnBehalfOf] [varchar](50) NULL,
[lastRedirectRedirectOnBehalfOf] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origCalledPartyRedirectReason] [varchar](50) NULL,
[lastRedirectRedirectReason] [varchar](50) NULL,
[destConversationId] [varchar](50) NULL,
[globalCallId_ClusterID] [varchar](50) NULL,
[joinOnBehalfOf] [varchar](50) NULL,
[comment] [varchar](50) NULL,
[authCodeDescription] [varchar](50) NULL,
[authorizationLevel] [varchar](50) NULL,
[clientMatterCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origDTMFMethod] [varchar](50) NULL,
[destDTMFMethod] [varchar](50) NULL,
[callSecuredStatus] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origConversationId] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origMediaCap_Bandwidth] [varchar](50) NULL,
[destMediaCap_Bandwidth] [varchar](50) NULL,
[authorizationCodeValue] [varchar](50) NULL,
[outpulsedCallingPartyNumber] [varchar](50) NULL,
[outpulsedCalledPartyNumber] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origIpv4v6Addr] [varchar](50) NULL,
[destIpv4v6Addr] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origVideoCap_Codec_Channel2] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origVideoCap_Bandwidth_Channel2] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origVideoCap_Resolution_Channel2] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origVideoTransportAddress_IP_Channel2] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origVideoTransportAddress_Port_Channel2] [varchar](50) NULL,
[origVideoChannel_Role_Channel2] [varchar](50) NULL,
[destVideoCap_Codec_Channel2] [varchar](50) NULL,
[destVideoCap_Bandwidth_Channel2] [varchar](50) NULL,
[destVideoCap_Resolution_Channel2] [varchar](50) NULL,
[destVideoTransportAddress_IP_Channel2] [varchar](50) NULL,
[destVideoTransportAddress_Port_Channel2] [varchar](50) NULL,
[destVideoChannel_Role_Channel2] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Second:

create new text file `C:\sqldata\myDatafile.txt` then copy the below data and paste it in that file:

```
"cdrRecordType","globalCallID_callManagerId","globalCallID_callId","origLegCallIdentifier","dateTimeOrigination","origNodeId","origSpan","origIpAddr","callingPartyNumber","callingPartyUnicodeLoginUserID","origCause_location","origCause_value","origPrecedenceLevel","origMediaTransportAddress_IP","origMediaTransportAddress_Port","origMediaCap_payloadCapability","origMediaCap_maxFramesPerPacket","origMediaCap_g723BitRate","origVideoCap_Codec","origVideoCap_Bandwidth","origVideoCap_Resolution","origVideoTransportAddress_IP","origVideoTransportAddress_Port","origRSVPAudioStat","origRSVPVideoStat","destLegIdentifier","destNodeId","destSpan","destIpAddr","originalCalledPartyNumber","finalCalledPartyNumber","finalCalledPartyUnicodeLoginUserID","destCause_location","destCause_value","destPrecedenceLevel","destMediaTransportAddress_IP","destMediaTransportAddress_Port","destMediaCap_payloadCapability","destMediaCap_maxFramesPerPacket","destMediaCap_g723BitRate","destVideoCap_Codec","destVideoCap_Bandwidth","destVideoCap_Resolution","destVideoTransportAddress_IP","destVideoTransportAddress_Port","destRSVPAudioStat","destRSVPVideoStat","dateTimeConnect","dateTimeDisconnect","lastRedirectDn","pkid","originalCalledPartyNumberPartition","callingPartyNumberPartition","finalCalledPartyNumberPartition","lastRedirectDnPartition","duration","origDeviceName","destDeviceName","origCallTerminationOnBehalfOf","destCallTerminationOnBehalfOf","origCalledPartyRedirectOnBehalfOf","lastRedirectRedirectOnBehalfOf","origCalledPartyRedirectReason","lastRedirectRedirectReason","destConversationId","globalCallId_ClusterID","joinOnBehalfOf","comment","authCodeDescription","authorizationLevel","clientMatterCode","origDTMFMethod","destDTMFMethod","callSecuredStatus","origConversationId","origMediaCap_Bandwidth","destMediaCap_Bandwidth","authorizationCodeValue","outpulsedCallingPartyNumber","outpulsedCalledPartyNumber","origIpv4v6Addr","destIpv4v6Addr","origVideoCap_Codec_Channel2","origVideoCap_Bandwidth_Channel2","origVideoCap_Resolution_Channel2","origVideoTransportAddress_IP_Channel2","origVideoTransportAddress_Port_Channel2","origVideoChannel_Role_Channel2","destVideoCap_Codec_Channel2","destVideoCap_Bandwidth_Channel2","destVideoCap_Resolution_Channel2","destVideoTransportAddress_IP_Channel2","destVideoTransportAddress_Port_Channel2","destVideoChannel_Role_Channel2"
    INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,VARCHAR(50),VARCHAR(128),INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,VARCHAR(64),VARCHAR(64),INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,VARCHAR(50),VARCHAR(50),VARCHAR(128),INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,VARCHAR(64),VARCHAR(64),INTEGER,INTEGER,VARCHAR(50),UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,VARCHAR(50),VARCHAR(50),VARCHAR(50),VARCHAR(50),INTEGER,VARCHAR(129),VARCHAR(129),INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,VARCHAR(50),INTEGER,VARCHAR(2048),VARCHAR(50),INTEGER,VARCHAR(32),INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,VARCHAR(32),VARCHAR(50),VARCHAR(50),VARCHAR(64),VARCHAR(64),INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER
    1,2,2759873,35208306,1330847184,2,0,-637263956,"5838","",0,0,4,-637263956,24692,4,20,0,0,0,0,0,0,"0","0",35208307,6,35208307,-2096103670,"90556138315","90556138315","",0,16,4,-2096103670,23090,4,20,0,0,0,0,0,0,"0","0",1330847195,1330847219,"90556138315","37d523ab-680b-41a9-ab6b-d9867974f044","Part_National","Part_DU_CCs_NAT","Part_National","Part_National",24,"SEP180373C4463E","10.255.15.131",0,12,0,0,0,0,0,"StandAloneCluster",0,"","",0,"",3,1,0,0,64,64,"","043699155","90556138315","172.31.4.218","10.255.15.131",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    1,2,2759107,35206523,1330846644,2,35206523,-737214710,"042861396","",0,0,4,-2129658102,19000,4,20,0,0,0,0,0,0,"0","0",35206524,7,0,1562582956,"6894","6894","",0,16,4,1562582956,18658,4,20,0,0,0,0,0,0,"0","0",1330846645,1330847219,"6894","a1df3ed4-0b42-4974-8c60-50cb9d696d5c","Part_India","","Part_India","Part_India",574,"10.255.14.212","SEP00269944A143",0,12,0,0,0,0,0,"StandAloneCluster",0,"","",0,"",1,3,0,0,64,64,"","","","10.255.15.129","172.31.35.93",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Third:

This is the file format: `C:\sqldata\CDRimport.fmt`

```
    10.0
    94
    1       SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      1     cdrRecordType                                                                      Arabic_CI_AS
    2       SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      2     globalCallID_callManagerId                                                         Arabic_CI_AS
    3       SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      3     globalCallID_callId                                                                Arabic_CI_AS
    4       SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      4     origLegCallIdentifier                                                              Arabic_CI_AS
    5       SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      5     dateTimeOrigination                                                                Arabic_CI_AS
    6       SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      6     origNodeId                                                                         Arabic_CI_AS
    7       SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      7     origSpan                                                                           Arabic_CI_AS
    8       SQLCHAR             0       50      ",\""      8     origIpAddr                                                                         Arabic_CI_AS
    9       SQLCHAR             0       50      "\",\""           9     callingPartyNumber                                                                 Arabic_CI_AS
    10      SQLCHAR             0       50      "\","      10    callingPartyUnicodeLoginUserID                                                     Arabic_CI_AS
    11      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      11    origCause_location                                                                 Arabic_CI_AS
    12      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      12    origCause_value                                                                    Arabic_CI_AS
    13      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      13    origPrecedenceLevel                                                                Arabic_CI_AS
    14      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      14    origMediaTransportAddress_IP                                                       Arabic_CI_AS
    15      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      15    origMediaTransportAddress_Port                                                     Arabic_CI_AS
    16      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      16    origMediaCap_payloadCapability                                                     Arabic_CI_AS
    17      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      17    origMediaCap_maxFramesPerPacket                                                    Arabic_CI_AS
    18      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      18    origMediaCap_g723BitRate                                                           Arabic_CI_AS
    19      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      19    origVideoCap_Codec                                                                 Arabic_CI_AS
    20      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      20    origVideoCap_Bandwidth                                                             Arabic_CI_AS
    21      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      21    origVideoCap_Resolution                                                            Arabic_CI_AS
    22      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      22    origVideoTransportAddress_IP                                                       Arabic_CI_AS
    23      SQLCHAR             0       50      ",\""      23    origVideoTransportAddress_Port                                                     Arabic_CI_AS
    24      SQLCHAR             0       50      "\",\""      24    origRSVPAudioStat                                                                  Arabic_CI_AS
    25      SQLCHAR             0       50      "\","      25    origRSVPVideoStat                                                                  Arabic_CI_AS
    26      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      26    destLegIdentifier                                                                  Arabic_CI_AS
    27      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      27    destNodeId                                                                         Arabic_CI_AS
    28      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      28    destSpan                                                                           Arabic_CI_AS
    29      SQLCHAR             0       50      ",\""      29    destIpAddr                                                                         Arabic_CI_AS
    30      SQLCHAR             0       50      "\",\""     30    originalCalledPartyNumber                                                          Arabic_CI_AS
    31      SQLCHAR             0       50      "\",\""     31    finalCalledPartyNumber                                                             Arabic_CI_AS
    32      SQLCHAR             0       50      "\","     32    finalCalledPartyUnicodeLoginUserID                                                 Arabic_CI_AS
    33      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      33    destCause_location                                                                 Arabic_CI_AS
    34      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      34    destCause_value                                                                    Arabic_CI_AS
    35      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      35    destPrecedenceLevel                                                                Arabic_CI_AS
    36      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      36    destMediaTransportAddress_IP                                                       Arabic_CI_AS
    37      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      37    destMediaTransportAddress_Port                                                     Arabic_CI_AS
    38      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      38    destMediaCap_payloadCapability                                                     Arabic_CI_AS
    39      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      39    destMediaCap_maxFramesPerPacket                                                    Arabic_CI_AS
    40      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      40    destMediaCap_g723BitRate                                                           Arabic_CI_AS
    41      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      41    destVideoCap_Codec                                                                 Arabic_CI_AS
    42      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      42    destVideoCap_Bandwidth                                                             Arabic_CI_AS
    43      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      43    destVideoCap_Resolution                                                            Arabic_CI_AS
    44      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      44    destVideoTransportAddress_IP                                                       Arabic_CI_AS
    45      SQLCHAR             0       50      ",\""      45    destVideoTransportAddress_Port                                                     Arabic_CI_AS
    46      SQLCHAR             0       50      "\",\""      46    destRSVPAudioStat                                                                  Arabic_CI_AS
    47      SQLCHAR             0       50      "\","      47    destRSVPVideoStat                                                                  Arabic_CI_AS
    48      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      48    dateTimeConnect                                                                    Arabic_CI_AS
    49      SQLCHAR             0       50      ",\""      49    dateTimeDisconnect                                                                 Arabic_CI_AS
    50      SQLCHAR             0       50      "\",\""      50    lastRedirectDn                                                                     Arabic_CI_AS
    51      SQLCHAR             0       50      "\",\""      51    pkid                                                                               Arabic_CI_AS
    52      SQLCHAR             0       50      "\",\""      52    originalCalledPartyNumberPartition                                                 Arabic_CI_AS
    53      SQLCHAR             0       50      "\",\""      53    callingPartyNumberPartition                                                        Arabic_CI_AS
    54      SQLCHAR             0       50      "\",\""      54    finalCalledPartyNumberPartition                                                    Arabic_CI_AS
    55      SQLCHAR             0       50      "\","      55    lastRedirectDnPartition                                                            Arabic_CI_AS
    56      SQLCHAR             0       50      ",\""      56    duration                                                                           Arabic_CI_AS
    57      SQLCHAR             0       50      "\",\""      57    origDeviceName                                                                     Arabic_CI_AS
    58      SQLCHAR             0       50      "\","      58    destDeviceName                                                                     Arabic_CI_AS
    59      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      59    origCallTerminationOnBehalfOf                                                      Arabic_CI_AS
    60      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      60    destCallTerminationOnBehalfOf                                                      Arabic_CI_AS
    61      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      61    origCalledPartyRedirectOnBehalfOf                                                  Arabic_CI_AS
    62      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      62    lastRedirectRedirectOnBehalfOf                                                     Arabic_CI_AS
    63      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      63    origCalledPartyRedirectReason                                                      Arabic_CI_AS
    64      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      64    lastRedirectRedirectReason                                                         Arabic_CI_AS
    65      SQLCHAR             0       50      ",\""      65    destConversationId                                                                 Arabic_CI_AS
    66      SQLCHAR             0       50      "\","      66    globalCallId_ClusterID                                                             Arabic_CI_AS
    67      SQLCHAR             0       50      ",\""      67    joinOnBehalfOf                                                                     Arabic_CI_AS
    68      SQLCHAR             0       50      "\",\""      68    comment                                                                            Arabic_CI_AS
    69      SQLCHAR             0       50      "\","      69    authCodeDescription                                                                Arabic_CI_AS
    70      SQLCHAR             0       50      ",\""      70    authorizationLevel                                                                 Arabic_CI_AS
    71      SQLCHAR             0       50      "\","      71    clientMatterCode                                                                   Arabic_CI_AS
    72      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      72    origDTMFMethod                                                                     Arabic_CI_AS
    73      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      73    destDTMFMethod                                                                     Arabic_CI_AS
    74      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      74    callSecuredStatus                                                                  Arabic_CI_AS
    75      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      75    origConversationId                                                                 Arabic_CI_AS
    76      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      76    origMediaCap_Bandwidth                                                             Arabic_CI_AS
    77      SQLCHAR             0       50      ",\""      77    destMediaCap_Bandwidth                                                             Arabic_CI_AS
    78      SQLCHAR             0       50      "\",\""      78    authorizationCodeValue                                                             Arabic_CI_AS
    79      SQLCHAR             0       50      "\",\""      79    outpulsedCallingPartyNumber                                                        Arabic_CI_AS
    80      SQLCHAR             0       50      "\",\""      80    outpulsedCalledPartyNumber                                                         Arabic_CI_AS
    81      SQLCHAR             0       50      "\",\""      81    origIpv4v6Addr                                                                     Arabic_CI_AS
    82      SQLCHAR             0       50      "\","      82    destIpv4v6Addr                                                                     Arabic_CI_AS
    83      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      83    origVideoCap_Codec_Channel2                                                        Arabic_CI_AS
    84      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      84    origVideoCap_Bandwidth_Channel2                                                    Arabic_CI_AS
    85      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      85    origVideoCap_Resolution_Channel2                                                   Arabic_CI_AS
    86      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      86    origVideoTransportAddress_IP_Channel2                                              Arabic_CI_AS
    87      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      87    origVideoTransportAddress_Port_Channel2                                            Arabic_CI_AS
    88      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      88    origVideoChannel_Role_Channel2                                                     Arabic_CI_AS
    89      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      89    destVideoCap_Codec_Channel2                                                        Arabic_CI_AS
    90      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      90    destVideoCap_Bandwidth_Channel2                                                    Arabic_CI_AS
    91      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      91    destVideoCap_Resolution_Channel2                                                   Arabic_CI_AS
    92      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      92    destVideoTransportAddress_IP_Channel2                                              Arabic_CI_AS
    93      SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      93    destVideoTransportAddress_Port_Channel2                                            Arabic_CI_AS
    94      SQLCHAR             0       50      "\n"   94    destVideoChannel_Role_Channel2                                                     Arabic_CI_AS
```

Finally, run this SQL command:

```
BULK INSERT CDR FROM 'C:\sqldata\myDatafile.txt' 
WITH (FORMATFILE='C:\sqldata\CDRimport.fmt', FIRSTROW=3)
```

It should insert 2 rows, however it only inserts 1 row. Does anyone have any idea why this is the case?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029384/sql-bulk-insert-with-firstrow-parameter-skips-the-following-line)

Comment: As a hint - for a next question, or for trying to diagnose a problem like this: **reduce it** to the minimal size that shows the problem! Don't make us create a table with a gazillion columns - two or three are more than enough! Try to make a really small reproduction of the problem - then understand why it's going wrong (which is probably easier with the smaller problem case, too!)

Answer (score 1):

From books online:
"The FIRSTROW attribute is not intended to skip column headers."
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms188365(v=sql.90).aspx

Basically, MS is moving away from Bulk Insert/bcp, in favor of SSIS.

The reason your header rows are throwing off the bulk insert is that your format file specifies that a row should always have exactly 57 commas, 36 quote and comma combinations, and a newline (order matters too.)  Since your second header row doesn't have the quote-comma delimeters, it's going to the next line to find the rest of the columns.  By the way, bulk insert also doesn't support extra delimiters in your values, even if they're escaped or contained within quotes.  Based on your format file, I'm guessing you anticipate they might.

Comment: I took a quick glance at your file, and I think that the reason for the missing row is the extra quotes in the first header row, and missing quotes in the second row.  Note that in your format file there is nowhere to specify a row delimiter, only field delimiters, which must be parsed in order.

Comment: Yes, but this is not my case. i dont want to valid the headers.

Comment: I think the issue is actually the converse; it does not support _not_ validating the header rows.  In other words I read it as the header rows have to match the same delimiter formats as the data rows. I've updated my answer with some details.