# SQL Server 2012 - Bulk Insert FIRSTROW = 2 skips the 2nd row

Tags: sql-server-2012, bulkinsert

I need to skip the first and last rows in a text file.  To do this, I first bulk insert the file without parsing the fields and count how many rows it has it in a staging table.  Then I use this dynamic sql code to insert the file into my table:

```
SELECT @last_row = MAX(id)
FROM Pre_Staging_Table

SELECT @last_row = CAST(@last_row AS BIGINT) - 1

SELECT @bulk_insert =
'
BULK INSERT Staging_Table
FROM ''' + @filename + '''
WITH
(
FIRSTROW = 2
, LASTROW = ' + @last_row + '
, FIELDTERMINATOR = ''' + @field_terminator + '''
, ROWTERMINATOR = ''' + CHAR(10) + '''
)
'
EXEC(@bulk_insert)
```

The problem... It starts the final bulk insert using the 3rd row of the file!  Why in the world is this happening?  When I do the bulk insert for the pre-staging table, all rows get inserted.  I do not do any FIRSTROW or LASTROW filter there.

Here are the first 4 rows of my data file:

```
09.0|A|DATA|START|20140626|20140626|005221|A|
346| |001|33  |P|FLIP       |2014|00000|00|L|O|0|       |0000000015|0| |     |SNAP       |19|000350000|00100|    |        |      |    | | |          |      |                                                                                          |4|000|     |  |AA   |2014|01|01|       |#
346| |001|33  | |FLIP       |2014|00000|00|L|O|0|       |0000000150|0| |     |SNAP       |00|000000000|00100|    |        |      |    | | |          |      |                                                                                          |4|000|     |  |AA   |2014|01|01|       |#
346| |001|33  |P|FLIP       |2014|00000|00|L|O|0|       |0000000027|0| |     |SNAP       |22|000125000|00100|    |        |      |    | | |          |      |                                                                                          |4|000|     |  |AA   |2014|01|01|       |#
```

The lines end with LF, not CRLF.  So I'm wondering if my code is having problems with that.  I read the other thread and that did not solve the problem since it looks like my header row does contain at least one delimiter as found in the other rows.

UPDATE: I have gotten around this by exporting the data in the pre-staging table into a new text file with only the rows I want and then re-importing them.

Comment: OP, please see the accepted answer to this question, as I think it likely addresses your issue: [SQL Bulk Insert with FIRSTROW parameter skips the following line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029384/sql-bulk-insert-with-firstrow-parameter-skips-the-following-line)

Comment: NOTE: At this point it is unclear if this is a duplicate...

Comment: Please show us the first 4 or 5 lines of your file, there's likely a problem with the header and/or data formatting.

Comment: I've updated the original post with the data.  The thread that was linked to was helpful, but I don't think it applies since all my rows contain at least one vertical bar delimiter.