# SSIS Foreach Loop Container to read files and load into DB getting crash during execution

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, etl, foreach-loop-container

I'm trying to load multiple files from a location into DB using **Foreach Loop Container** & **DataFlow task** in **SSIS**.

It's getting crashed while I try to execute the package. It's not giving any error message, whenever I execute the package it crashes and closes the visual studio app immediately. I have to kill the debug task in the task manager for the next execution of the package.

So I tried the below steps:

1. I used a **FileSystem task** instead of **DataFlow task** to just
   move all the files from the source to the archive directory, which ran
   fine without any issues.

[image]

[image]

2. Ran the **DataFlow task** individually to load a single file into DB,
   which was also executed successfully.

I couldn't figure out what was going wrong here. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

---

**Screenshots**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should add the error message, more information about the Foreach loop container and the data flow task, how variables are used to import the data dynamically. Moreover, adding screenshots will make it easier to understand more details.

Comment: Sure, will add the screenshots.. Actually its not giving any error message, whenever I execute the package it crashes and closes the visual studio.. I have to kill the debug task in task manager before the next execution of the pkg..

Comment: you should also mention that in the question

Comment: okay, will include this info as well, thanks..

Comment: still there are several required screenshots: (1) The ForEach Loop Container Editor: (a) the variables mapping tab, (b) foreach configuration tab, (c) Expressions used (since the screenshots show the `fx` mark on the container). (2) The Flat File connection manager expressions. (since you are loading file dynamically)

Comment: @Hadi Guess I have included all the required screenshots.. Let me know for any additional details..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**All screenshots look fine to me. I will give some tips to try to figure out the issue.**

Since the *File System Task* is executed without any problem, there is no problem with the *ForEach Loop Container*. You can try to remove the *OLE DB Destination* and replace it with a dummy task to check if it causing the issue. If the issue remains, it means that the *Flat File Source* could be the cause.

#### Things to try

1. Make sure that the `TargetServerVersion` is accurate. You can learn more about this property in the following article: [How to change TargetServerVersion of my SSIS Project](https://zappysys.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001710233-How-to-change-TargetServerVersion-of-my-SSIS-Project)
2. Try running the package in 32-bit mode. You can do this by changing the `Run64bitRuntime` property to `False`. You can learn more about this property in the following article: [Run64bitRunTime debugging property](https://bageshkumarbagi-msbi.blogspot.com/2018/03/run64bitruntime-debugging-property.html)
3. Running Visual Studio in safe mode. You can use the following command `devenv.exe /safemode`.

#### Workaround - Using Bulk Insert

Since you are inserting flat files into the SQL database without performing any transformation. Why not use the [SSIS Bulk Insert Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/bulk-insert-task?view=sql-server-ver15). You can refer to the following step-by-step guide for more information:

- [SSIS Basics: Bulk-Import various text files into a table](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ssis-basics-bulk-import-various-text-files-into-a-table)

As mentioned in the official documentation, make sure that the following requirements are met:

- The server must have permission to access both the file and the destination database.
- The server runs the Bulk Insert task. Therefore, any format file that the task uses must be located on the server.
- The source file that the Bulk Insert task loads can be on the same server as the SQL Server database into which data is inserted, or on a remote server. If the file is on a remote server, you must specify the file name using the Universal Naming Convention (UNC) name in the path.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs! Bulk Insert ran without any issue. Is it possible to configure Bulk Insert to skip headers(FirstRow) in the file?

Comment: @Vicky https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029384/sql-bulk-insert-with-firstrow-parameter-skips-the-following-line

Comment: @Vicky If this answer solved your issue feel free to [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: sure, thanks so much for your help!!